# WhenEvent disabled in NDsolve

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

I try to simulate particle motion in electric field. Ex and Ey is the intensity of electric field in X axis and y axis resepectively, which is related to the position of particle.

```m
g = 9.8; q = 1.08 10^-13;
s = NDSolve[{m x''[t] + 6 \[Pi] \[Eta] R x'[t] == q Ex[x[t], y[t], t],
     m y''[t] + 6 \[Pi] \[Eta] R y'[t] == q Ey[x[t], y[t], t] - m g, 
    x[0] == 0, y[0] == 100 b, x'[0] == y'[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[1 b < y[t] < 5 b, y'[t] -> -0.35 y'[t]]}, {x, y}, {t, 0,
     0.1}, Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 2, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 4, Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False},
    MaxStepSize -> 10^-6];
StepDataPlot[s]
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 0.1}]
```

WhenEvent describes that when particle land on the plane, it will bounce. Initially, I wrote like this
`WhenEvent[y[t]==0, y'[t] -> -0.35 y'[t]]}`

[image]

I thought Ndsovle might miss the point. So I enlarge the the section of WhenEvent and minimize the Max step size. But it still doesnot work.

I do not know Whether I set the parameters wrong or use the wrong method.

Sometimes, it will notes that Singularity or stiffness problesm, so I add "StiffnessSwitching". And the function of Ex and Ey is piecewise periodic function, so I add `Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}`

I am a rookie in using NDsolve. I am still learning it in dealing with particle trajectories. Thank you very much for any constructive ideas.

Here is complete code. Most of the previous ones are for calculating the electric field. If you have time to comb through the code, just run it. Thanks again.

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
\[Epsilon] = 8.854187817 10^-12;
vc0 = 0.8 10^3;
a = 0.3 10^-3;
b = 18 10^-6;
dx = a;
l = 4 a + 4 dx;
n1 = 40;
n2 = 6;
k1 = 1/6;
k2 = 1/6;
TT = 0.2;
\[Delta]1 = a/n1; \[Delta]2 = b/n2; s1 = k1 \[Delta]1; s2 = 
 k2 \[Delta]2; c = a - 2 s2; d = b - 2 s1; \[Delta]3 = 
 c/n1; \[Delta]4 = d/n2; n = 2 (n1 + n2);
(*1*)xa1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
   Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
ya1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xa2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
   Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
ya2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*2*)xb1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   a + dx;
yb1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xb2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + a + dx;
yb2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*3*)xc1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   2 (a + dx);
yc1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xc2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 2 (a + dx);
yc2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*4*)xd1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   3 (a + dx);
yd1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xd2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 3 (a + dx);
yd2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*5*)xe1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   4 (a + dx);
ye1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xe2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 4 (a + dx);
ye2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*6*)xf1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   5 (a + dx);
yf1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xf2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 5 (a + dx);
yf2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*7*)xg1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   6 (a + dx);
yg1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xg2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 6 (a + dx);
yg2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*8*)xh1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   7 (a + dx);
yh1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xh2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 7 (a + dx);
yh2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

x1 = Join[xa1, xb1, xc1, xd1, xe1, xf1, xg1, xh1];
y1 = Join[ya1, yb1, yc1, yd1, ye1, yf1, yg1, yh1];
x2 = Join[xa2, xb2, xc2, xd2, xe2, xf2, xg2, xh2];
y2 = Join[ya2, yb2, yc2, yd2, ye2, yf2, yg2, yh2];
p0[i_, k_] := -(1/(4 \[Pi] \[Epsilon])) Log[(x1[[i]] - 
        x2[[k]])^2 + (y1[[i]] - y2[[k]])^2];
p = Table[p0[i, k], {i, 1, 8 n}, {k, 1, 8 n}];
vc1 = Join[Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], 
   Table[-vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], 
   Table[-vc0, n]];
vc2 = Join[Table[-vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], 
   Table[-vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], 
   Table[-vc0, n]];
vc3 = Join[Table[-vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], 
   Table[vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], 
   Table[vc0, n]];
vc4 = Join[Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], 
   Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], 
   Table[vc0, n]];(*Voltage of electrodes*)
\[Lambda]1 = LinearSolve[p, vc1, Method -> "Multifrontal"];
\[Lambda]2 = LinearSolve[p, vc2, Method -> "Multifrontal"];
\[Lambda]3 = LinearSolve[p, vc3, Method -> "Multifrontal"];
\[Lambda]4 = LinearSolve[p, vc4, Method -> "Multifrontal"];
ClearAll[\[Lambda]];
\[Lambda][t_?NumericQ] := 
  Which[t >= TT, \[Lambda][t - TT], t < 0, \[Lambda][t + TT], 
   0 <= t < TT/4, \[Lambda]1, TT/4 <= t < TT/2, \[Lambda]2, 
   TT/2 <= t < 3 TT/4, \[Lambda]3, 3 TT/4 <= t < TT, \[Lambda]4];
ex0[x_, y_, t_, k_] := 
  Indexed[\[Lambda][t], k]/(2 \[Pi] \[Epsilon]) (
   x - x2[[k]])/((x - x2[[k]])^2 + (y - y2[[k]])^2);
ey0[x_, y_, t_, k_] := 
  Indexed[\[Lambda][t], k]/(2 \[Pi] \[Epsilon]) (
   y - y2[[k]])/((x - x2[[k]])^2 + (y - y2[[k]])^2);
Ex[x_, y_, t_] := Sum[ex0[x, y, t, k], {k, 1, 8 n}];
Ex[x_?NumericQ, y_, t_] := 
  which[x >= 6 a + 11 dx/2, Ex[x, y, t] = Ex[x - 4 a - 4 dx, y, t], 
   x < 2 a + 3 dx/2, Ex[x, y, t] = Ex[x + 4 a + 4 dx, y, t], 
   2 a + 3 dx/2 <= x < 6 a + 11 dx/2, Ex[x, y, t]];
Ey[x_, y_, t_] := Sum[ey0[x, y, t, k], {k, 1, 8 n}];
Ey[x_?NumericQ, y_, t_] := 
  which[x >= 6 a + 11 dx/2, Ey[x, y, t] = Ey[x - 4 a - 4 dx, y, t], 
   x < 2 a + 3 dx/2, Ex[x, y, t] = Ex[x + 4 a + 4 dx, y, t], 
   2 a + 3 dx/2 <= x < 6 a + 11 dx/2, Ey[x, y, t]];
m = 1.8 10^-9; \[Eta] = 1.8 10^-5; R = 5 10^-5;
g = 9.8; q = 1.08 10^-13;
s = NDSolve[{m x''[t] + 6 \[Pi] \[Eta] R x'[t] == q Ex[x[t], y[t], t],
     m y''[t] + 6 \[Pi] \[Eta] R y'[t] == q Ey[x[t], y[t], t] - m g, 
    x[0] == 0, y[0] == 100 b, x'[0] == y'[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -0.35 y'[t]]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 0.02},
    AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
   Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 0.02}]
```

It seems the event is identified at the first red circle point. However, after that point, the event will be ignored.

Electric field Distribution. Red line reprensents Ey and blue line reprensents Ex.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you, please, post a MWE? Thanks!

Comment: @Yuuu There are several typos in your code, for example,  `which` should be `Which`. It looks like you try to define piecewise function without `Piecewise`.

Comment: @ CA Trevillian, sorry, what's MWE? Do you mean megawatt electrical? I will post the eletric field distribution at a certian height. @Alex Trounev, Thanks for pointing out that error. I corrected it, but Ndsovle still seems to ignore the WhenEvent.

Comment: @Yuuu What kind of  electric field do you try to calculate?

Comment: @ Alex Trounev, I'd like calculate electric field of parallel arrayed electrodes. I precalculate four electrodes and use it as a cycle domain. The electric field distribution is added in the question, black line in the X axis are electrodes. Hope it can make the problem clearer.

Comment: @Yuuu Why don't you use FEM to compute electric field? Your method and code very unusual. Are these expressions for `ex0, ey0` taken from some book or paper?

Comment: @ Alex Yes, I want to try a new method, named Charge simulation method. I used FEM by COMSOL, it may be not so accurate and suitable for my problems. I compared the results of CSM with other methods, which seems works well. But when I inserted it to NDsolve. There are a lot of problems with the program.

Comment: Site tip: To reply to a user, use @user with no spaces after the @ or in their name.  Otherwise they might not be notified of your reply.  See [here for discussions of MWEs](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=minimal+working).

Answer (score 5):

After several typos correction in  `Ex, Ey` definition we run code up to final result at `t=0.1` with Method -> "ExplicitEuler"

```
\[Epsilon] = 8.854187817 10^-12;
vc0 = 0.8 10^3;
a = 0.3 10^-3;
b = 18 10^-6;
dx = a;
l = 4 a + 4 dx;
n1 = 40;
n2 = 6;
k1 = 1/6;
k2 = 1/6;
TT = 0.2;
\[Delta]1 = a/n1; \[Delta]2 = b/n2; s1 = k1 \[Delta]1; s2 = 
 k2 \[Delta]2; c = a - 2 s2; d = b - 2 s1; \[Delta]3 = 
 c/n1; \[Delta]4 = d/n2; n = 2 (n1 + n2);
(*1*)xa1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
   Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
ya1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xa2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
   Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
ya2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*2*)xb1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   a + dx;
yb1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xb2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + a + dx;
yb2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*3*)xc1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   2 (a + dx);
yc1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xc2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 2 (a + dx);
yc2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*4*)xd1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   3 (a + dx);
yd1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xd2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 3 (a + dx);
yd2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*5*)xe1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   4 (a + dx);
ye1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xe2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 4 (a + dx);
ye2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*6*)xf1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   5 (a + dx);
yf1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xf2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 5 (a + dx);
yf2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*7*)xg1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   6 (a + dx);
yg1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xg2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 6 (a + dx);
yg2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

(*8*)xh1 = 
  Join[Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[a, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - i \[Delta]1, {i, 0, n1}], Table[0, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 
   7 (a + dx);
yh1 = Join[Table[b, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[0, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];
xh2 = Join[Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], 
    Table[a - s2 - i \[Delta]3, {i, 0, n1}], 
    Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]] + 7 (a + dx);
yh2 = Join[Table[b - s1, {i, 0, n1}], 
   Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}], Table[s1, {i, 0, n1}],
    Table[s1 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2 - 1}]];

x1 = Join[xa1, xb1, xc1, xd1, xe1, xf1, xg1, xh1];
y1 = Join[ya1, yb1, yc1, yd1, ye1, yf1, yg1, yh1];
x2 = Join[xa2, xb2, xc2, xd2, xe2, xf2, xg2, xh2];
y2 = Join[ya2, yb2, yc2, yd2, ye2, yf2, yg2, yh2];
p0[i_, k_] := -(1/(4 \[Pi] \[Epsilon])) Log[(x1[[i]] - 
        x2[[k]])^2 + (y1[[i]] - y2[[k]])^2];
p = Table[p0[i, k], {i, 1, 8 n}, {k, 1, 8 n}];
vc1 = Join[Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], 
   Table[-vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], 
   Table[-vc0, n]];
vc2 = Join[Table[-vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], 
   Table[-vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], 
   Table[-vc0, n]];
vc3 = Join[Table[-vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], 
   Table[vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], 
   Table[vc0, n]];
vc4 = Join[Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], 
  Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], 
  Table[vc0, n]];(*Voltage of electrodes*)\[Lambda]1 = 
 LinearSolve[p, vc1, Method -> "Multifrontal"];
\[Lambda]2 = LinearSolve[p, vc2, Method -> "Multifrontal"];
\[Lambda]3 = LinearSolve[p, vc3, Method -> "Multifrontal"];
\[Lambda]4 = LinearSolve[p, vc4, Method -> "Multifrontal"];
ClearAll[\[Lambda]];
\[Lambda][t_?NumericQ] := 
  Which[t >= TT, \[Lambda][t - TT], t < 0, \[Lambda][t + TT], 
   0 <= t < TT/4, \[Lambda]1, TT/4 <= t < TT/2, \[Lambda]2, 
   TT/2 <= t < 3 TT/4, \[Lambda]3, 3 TT/4 <= t < TT, \[Lambda]4];
ex0[x_, y_, t_, k_] := 
  Indexed[\[Lambda][t], 
     k]/(2 \[Pi] \[Epsilon]) (x - 
      x2[[k]])/((x - x2[[k]])^2 + (y - y2[[k]])^2);
ey0[x_, y_, t_, k_] := 
  Indexed[\[Lambda][t], 
     k]/(2 \[Pi] \[Epsilon]) (y - 
      y2[[k]])/((x - x2[[k]])^2 + (y - y2[[k]])^2);
Ex[x_, y_, t_] := Sum[ex0[x, y, t, k], {k, 1, 8 n}];
Ex1[x_?NumericQ, y_, t_] := 
  Which[x >= 6 a + 11 dx/2, Ex[x - 4 a - 4 dx, y, t], 
   x < 2 a + 3 dx/2, Ex[x + 4 a + 4 dx, y, t], 
   2 a + 3 dx/2 <= x < 6 a + 11 dx/2, Ex[x, y, t]];
Ey[x_, y_, t_] := Sum[ey0[x, y, t, k], {k, 1, 8 n}];
Ey1[x_?NumericQ, y_, t_] := 
  Which[x >= 6 a + 11 dx/2, Ey[x - 4 a - 4 dx, y, t], 
   x < 2 a + 3 dx/2, Ex[x + 4 a + 4 dx, y, t], 
   2 a + 3 dx/2 <= x < 6 a + 11 dx/2, Ey[x, y, t]];
```

It looks like `WhenEvent` works good in this evaluation, but particle moving in region `x<0`

```
m = 1.8 10^-9; \[Eta] = 1.8 10^-5; R = 5 10^-5;
g = 9.8; q = 1.08 10^-13; s = 
 NDSolve[{m x''[t] + 6 \[Pi] \[Eta] R x'[t] == q Ex1[x[t], y[t], t], 
   m y''[t] + 6 \[Pi] \[Eta] R y'[t] == q Ey1[x[t], y[t], t] - m g, 
   x[0] == 0, y[0] == 100 b, x'[0] == y'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -0.35 y'[t]]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 0.1}, StartingStepSize -> 10^-4, Method -> "ExplicitEuler"
  ];

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s], {t, 0, 0.1}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image: Figure 1]

If particle bouncing not only from the bottom, but also from the top, then we can use combined rule as follows

```
WhenEvent[{y[t] == 0, y[t] == 101 b}, y'[t] -> -0.35 y'[t]]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Modified code for long time computation

```
m = 1.8 10^-9; \[Eta] = 1.8 10^-5; R = 5 10^-5;
g = 9.8; q = 1.08 10^-13;
s = NDSolve[{m x''[t] + 6 \[Pi] \[Eta] R x'[t] == q Ex[x[t], y[t], t],
    m y''[t] + 
     6 \[Pi] \[Eta] R y'[t] == (q Ey[x[t], y[t], t] - 
       m g) (Tanh[100 (y[t]/R - 1)] + 1)/2, x[0] == 0, y[0] == 100 b, 
   x'[0] == y'[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[y[t] == R && Abs[y'[t]] > R g, y'[t] -> -0.35 y'[t]], 
   WhenEvent[y[t] == R/2, y'[t] -> 0]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  StartingStepSize -> 10^-4, 
  Method -> 
   "ExplicitEuler"](*Method\[Rule]{"DoubleStep", \
Method\[Rule]"ExplicitEuler"}*)


ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. s[[1]]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thank you very much for going through the complete code. It works well now.  I am wondering the reason Ndsolve ignores the WhenEvent is the use of ```Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching",}```. Particle move direction is effected by electric field distribution. Under some parameters, it does travels in X<0.

Comment: In addition, when I set the solution time into 0.1 s.```s = NDSolve[{m x''[t] + 6 \[Pi] \[Eta] R x'[t] == 
     q Ex1[x[t], y[t], t], 
    m y''[t] + 6 \[Pi] \[Eta] R y'[t] == q Ey1[x[t], y[t], t] - m g, 
    x[0] == 0, y[0] == 100 b, x'[0] == y'[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[y[t] == 0, y'[t] -> -0.35 y'[t]]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 0.1}, 
   Method -> {"DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}];``` It will notes that ```NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.06778142044938072`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.```. Do you know how I can solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: That is why I add Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching",}

Comment: @Yuuu See update to my answer  for integration time up to `t=0.1`.

Comment: Cool and thanks. A different method can make a great change to the solution. I also tried several different methods for several days, none of which worked. I still know too little about NDsolve.Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, it is useful. I tried to vote it, but my reputation is less than 15, rookie here. So it will not be publicly displayed post score but only record. Once I got enough reputation, I will revote it. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry to interrupt you again. I want to change the initial value, which behaves like that particle lands on the plane at the start point, like y=20b. And when the electric force  in y axis is larger than gravitatational force, particle begins to move upward. How can I set the NDsovle and make it run successfuly.  I just tried to change a little in the NDsolve,  ```WhenEvent[y[t] == y[0], y'[t] -> -0.35 y'[t]```,but it seems can not solve it. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @Yuuu Please, see update to my answer.

Comment: I may not explain clearly. I mean what if y[0]=0, the start position is right on the plane. Then the particle starts to move upward.

Comment: @Yuuu Any way, this rule is wrong `y[t] == y[0]`. It could be better if we put `y[t]==0`. Don't try to use initial position in `WhenEvent` with `Method -> "ExplicitEuler"`. Let put for instance `y[0]==10 b`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I just tried to set y[0]==10b, the result was wrong again. The trajectroy of particl accrosses the plane. So I try to minimize the StartingStepSize -> 10^-5. It seems right.

Comment: @Yuuu Yes, it is right strategy to decrease time step.

Comment: Yes, there is one thing that the definition of Ex and Ey should be my previous form.```Ex[x_ /; 2 a + 3 dx/2 <= x < 6 a + 11 dx/2, y_, t_] := Sum[ex0[x, y, t, k], {k, 1, 8 n}];
Ex[x_?NumericQ, y_, t_] := Which[x >= 6 a + 11 dx/2, Ex[x, y, t] = Ex[x - 4 a - 4 dx, y, t], x < 2 a + 3 dx/2, Ex[x, y, t] = Ex[x + 4 a + 4 dx, y, t], 2 a + 3 dx/2 <= x < 6 a + 11 dx/2, Ex[x, y, t]];``` Because I want to intercept an interval value of Ex and then loop through the entire domain. I don't know if I explained it clearly.

Comment: In this form, if I want to add simulation time into 2 second, the result seems feasible. But if I add simulation time further into 10 seconds, I will get some weird trajectory, sort of linear. Therefore, I do not know how to change the set of the NDsolve. Could you please try to simulate it longer and see if some changes can be done to get a proper result?

Comment: It looks like `WhenEvent` not working for `y` close to 0. If particle moving along plate `y=0` it has a chance dropped down. It is why there is the line. Probably we should restrict region  by `y>0` not only with `WhenEvent`.

Comment: You are right. And how can we restrict the region and make NDsolve run accurately

Comment: What actually do you try to simulate?

Comment: I want to simulate the motion of charged particle in the electric field.  It’s like a small ball jumping on a tablet. When the particles fall at a certain height and start the simulation, as you provided, the calculation results are good. Then I want to simulate that the particle start to move right on the platform.

Comment: Model with `WhenEvent` is not suitable for this problem. Particles can recharge during collision.  There are surface roughness can effects as well.

Comment: Exactly. Do you know there are any models can simulate this?

Comment: @Yuuu I have modified code for long time computation.

Comment: Thanks for it. I will read it carefully. I'd like to chat with you but I still do not have enough reputation. If you do not mind, can we chat through email or other ways you like. Thank you very much for the improvements you made to the code.

Comment: @Yuuu You are welcome!